# How can I develop a class to return unique numbers in the specified range?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I need to develop a class to return unique numbers in the specified range. For example, if the specified range is 1-4, calling `GetNextNumber()` will work as follows:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj->min = 1;
obj->max = 4;
obj->expirationTime = 30; //seconds

int nextNumber = 0;
nextNumber = obj->GetNextNumber(); // returns 1
nextNumber = obj->GetNextNumber(); // returns 2
nextNumber = obj->GetNextNumber(); // returns 3
nextNumber = obj->GetNextNumber(); // returns 4
nextNumber = obj->GetNextNumber(); // returns -1 or throws an exception, becuase all numbers from 1 to 4 have been used.

obj->ReleaseNumber(2); // now that number 2 has been released, it can be used again
nextNumber = obj->GetNextNumber(); // returns 2
nextNumber = obj->GetNextNumber(); // returns -1 or throws an exception, becuase all numbers from 1 to 4 have been used.
```

If we do not call `ReleaseNumber()` on a number returned from `GetNextNumber()` it will be released and returned by `ReleaseNextExpiredNumber()` method.

```
// after 10 seconds:
int nextExpiredNumber = 0;
nextExpiredNumber = obj->ReleaseNextExpiredNumber(); // returns -1 or throws and exeption because nothing has been expired after 10 seconds
// after 30 seconds
nextExpiredNumber = obj->ReleaseNextExpiredNumber(); // returns 1, because "ReleaseNumber(1)" has not been called within 30 seconds.
// now that number 1 has been released, the `GetNextNumber()` method will return 1:
nextNumber = obj->GetNextNumber(); // returns 1
```

I am going to develop such class on my own, but before doing that, I want to make sure I am not reinventing the wheel. I also need this class to be thread-safe. Thank you for any advice!

Comment: @DrewMcGowen The numbers are supposed to be returned sequentially.

Comment: Say that you had 1, 2, and 3 allocated. Then `obj->ReleaseNumber(2)` was called. Is it OK for the next call to `obj->GetNextNumber()` to return 4, or does it need to return 2?

Comment: @JonathanMee It doesn't matter. Any approach that finds the next number faster is preferred. But numbers should not be returned totally randomly, returning them in sequence is better.

Comment: What should happen if multiple numbers are released by `ReleaseNextExpiredNumber`?

Comment: @JonathanMee `ReleaseNextExpiredNumber` releases those number which have not been explicitly released by calling `ReleaseNumber` after `expirationTime` seconds. If no such number exists,  `ReleaseNextExpiredNumber` will return -1.

Comment: I guess you intended the return of `ReleaseNextExpiredNumber` to be a `vector` then, not just an `int`?

Comment: @JonathanMee No, I meant returning only one expired number at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with numbers is just a matter of pushing and popping onto a container. I picked `deque` since it's efficient at `pop_front` and `push_back`:

```
class MyClass {
    std::deque<int> numbers;

public:
    MyClass(int lo, int hi) {
        numbers.resize(hi - lo + 1);
        std::iota(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), lo);
    }

    int getNextNumber() {
        if (!numbers.empty()) {
            int next = numbers[0];
            numbers.pop_front();
            return next;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    void releaseNumber(int i) {
        numbers.push_back(i);
    }
};
```

Adding times on top of that means you just have another container of values with timestamps:

```
using timestamp = std::chrono::system_clock::time_point; // or whatever
std::vector<std::pair<int, timestamp>> used;
```

And making `getNextNumber()` push onto that vector:

```
numbers.pop_front();
used.emplace_back(next, std::chrono::system_clock::now());
return next;
```

And `releaseNumber()` erase from it:

```
auto it = std::find_if(used.begin(), used.end(), 
    [=](const std::pair<int, timestamp>& p){
        return p.first == i;
    });
used.erase(it);
```

With that, `ReleaseNextExpiredNumber()` is just a matter of checking `used.front()`: if it's expired, return `releaseNumber()`, else return -1.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. Just one question, this implementation is not thread-safe, right?

Comment: @Meysam Not even a little bit :)

Comment: Do you think there is any faster way to `find` and `erase` a number from `used`? For wider ranges like 1-32000, `std::find_if` does not seem fast enough (suppose that the number to release is the last number found in the vector). Maybe you could use a `map` for that purpose?

Comment: @Meysam It depends on what you want to do more often - `releaseNumber()` vs `ReleaseNextExpiredNumber()`. An `unordered_map` makes the first one faster, a `vector` makes the second one faster.

Answer (score 1):

First off, since you're using a contiguous sequence of numbers, you can just use an array for mapping each number to a piece of data:

```
dataArray[number - min] = whateverData;
```

Where `dataArray` has `max - min - 1` elements (since both bounds are inclusive).

Second, you can use a simple `bool` array for whether or not a number is available (either a `bool[]` or `std::vector<bool>` will work).

As far as tracking expiration, you'll need to use the [`time`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/) function for getting timestamps, and an array of [`time_t`](http://www.cplusplus.com/time_t) structures which store the expiration time of each number. Then, your `ReleaseNextExpiredNumber` might look something like this:

```
time_t curTime = time(NULL); // get current time
for (int num = min; num <= max; num++) // or whatever number type you want
{
    if (available[num - min]) // skip available numbers
        continue;
    if (expirationTimes[num - min] > curTime) // you can compare via difftime
    {
        // release the number
        ReleaseNumber(num);
        return num;
    }
}
// nothing expired
return -1;
```

`GetNextNumber` is fairly simple:

```
time_t curTime = time();
for (int num = min; num <= max; num++)
{
    if (!available[num - min])) // skip unavailable numbers
        continue;
    // mark as used
    available[num - min] = false;
    // compute expiration time
    expirationTimes[num - min] = curTime + expirationTime; // or whatever function to add seconds to a time_t
    // return it
    return num;
}
// nothing available
return -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem primarily because it's hard to maintain the time queue and the available numbers. I decided to hold them separately.

Additionally if you expect a very large number of available numbers it is likely that a circular buffer of sorts would work better than my implementation.

You have `min` and `max` as public variables. I don't think that you can do that. You would need to update everything if one of those changed, potentially to the point of throwing out all your numbers. In my implementation I've just made them `const`.

Anyway, here's what I came up with:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    MyClass(int min, int max, int expirationTime) : _min(min), _max(max), _expirationTime(expirationTime), _isAvailable(_max - _min + 1, true) {}

    int getExpirationTime() const { return _expirationTime; }

    void setExpirationTime(int expirationTime){ _expirationTime = expirationTime; }

    int getNextNumber(){
        auto it = find(_isAvailable.begin(), _isAvailable.end(), true);
        auto result = it == _isAvailable.end() ? -1 : distance(_isAvailable.begin(), it) + _min;

        if (result > 0){
            *it = false;
            _fifo.push_back(make_pair(time(nullptr), result));
        }
        return result;
    }

    void releaseNumber(int number){
        assert(number >= _min && number <= _max);
        _isAvailable[number - _min] = true;
        _fifo.erase(find_if(_fifo.begin(), _fifo.end(), [&](const pair<time_t, int> i){ return i.second == number; }));
    }

    int releaseNextExpiredNumber(){
        auto result = -1;

        if(!_fifo.empty() && _fifo.front().first <= time(nullptr) + _expirationTime){
            result = _fifo.front().second;
            _isAvailable[result - _min] = true;
            _fifo.pop_front();
        }
        return result;
    }
private:
    const int _min;
    const int _max;
    int _expirationTime;
    vector<bool> _isAvailable;
    deque<pair<time_t, int>> _fifo;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Did you test it? Seems it's not working correctly: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a54f6de5b9cf4238

Comment: @Meysam Hrmmm... I hadn't considered what would happen if an element had been added back into the `queue`. I switched the answer to use a `deque` so that I can remove the entry when `releaseNumber` is called. This makes `_isAvailable` less beneficial though, and honestly in the event that the range is very small, it's probably a determent. I'm going to see if std::algorithm has anything to replace `_isAvailable`...